# No JavaDocs on hover for JavaFX in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I am using IntelliJ and I have JavaDocs on hover for everything except JavaFX stuff. Can somebody tell me how to enable it? I have looked on Editor Settings but I didn't find an option to add docs.

Comment: You need to attach sources or documentation to the JavaFX library in the project structure. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html#add-a-new-dependency. Did perform these steps?

Comment: I added them with the URL, but it's only written for example "javafx.collections.ObservableList<E> public abstract boolean addAll(E... es)". It doesn't write what the funcion does, like on StringBuilder's methods for example

Comment: Please add the configuration screenshot to your question.